# RDP Connection to Windows Server 2008 R2 WEB Edition

Tags: windows, rdp

Is RDP (at least one single session) is available in Windows SRV 2008 R2 WEB Edition? I.e. can I connect and configure the host remotely if host is running WEB Edition?

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use RDP to connect to Windows Server 2008 Web Edition.

I believe it is limited to 2 concurrent sessions.